# Excel not returning same values as Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this formula that works on Google Sheets:

```
=IF(ISERROR(
INDEX(Students!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(Students!$G:$G=$B$1,ROW(Students!$G:$G)),ROW(1:1)),C$1)),"DELETE",
INDEX(Students!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(Students!$G:$G=$B$1,ROW(Students!$G:$G)),ROW(1:1)),C$1))
```

It's returning a draggable list of students based on B1 (C1 selects the column)

However, when I download the .xlsx from Google Sheets and opened in in MS Excel, it does not return the students. It returns the 1 row (the header) and nothing else.
What can cause it?

EDIT: added snapshot
[image: snapshot]

[image]

Comment: It would help to see a snapshot of your sheet. Can you post a pic of your sheet?

Comment: certainly, ill edit a snapshot in

Comment: That helps but a snapshot of your 'Student' sheet would help to see how your data is laid out. Can you add that?

Comment: Alright, added it in as well

Comment: well your if criteria evaluates to false in excel, and therefore row(1) is taken.

Comment: but isnt it the same criteria? or are the functions I used in gsheets somehow different in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array formula, which Google is smart to recognise without the explicit use of <kbd>`ARRAYFORMULA`</kbd>, While Excel isn't. You need to enter the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> 
+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The formula should be automatically enclosed in flower brackets <kbd>`{`</kbd>  <kbd>`}`</kbd> , if you did it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you have to put it in as an array formula in Excel (shown here with some dummy data)

[image]

But the reason why you just get the first row is much less obvious (to me at any rate)

When you have a range and use it in formula like =G:G, Excel selects a different cell from the range depending where you put the formula (I forget what this mechanism is called?) so in this case the formula in B2 picks up 6-loyalty from Students!G2 and the IF statement gives TRUE and you end up with the smallest of (row) 1, which is just 1, so you get the first row. If you try to get the second smallest, you end up with an error.